# How to shift bits in big endian in c++

Tags: c++, endianness

Here is code for little endian bit shift, i want to convert it in big endian bit shift.
please help me out. actually this is LZW decompression code using little endian shift.
but i want big endian code

```
unsigned int input_code(FILE *input)
{
unsigned int val;
static int bitcount=0;
static unsigned long inbitbuf=0L;

  while (bitcount <= 24)
  {
      inbitbuf |=(unsigned long) getc(input) << (24-bitcount);
      bitcount += 8;
  }

  val=inbitbuf >> (32-BITS);
  inbitbuf <<= BITS;
  bitcount -= BITS;

  return(val);
}


void output_code(FILE *output,unsigned int code)
{
static int output_bit_count=0;
static unsigned long output_bit_buffer=0L;

output_bit_buffer |= (unsigned long) code << (32-BITS-output_bit_count);
output_bit_count += BITS;
while (output_bit_count >= 8)
{
    putc(output_bit_buffer >> 24,output);
    output_bit_buffer <<= 8;
    output_bit_count -= 8;
}
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that the file is big endian? The endianness of the platform doesn't matter in this case since no individual bytes in memory are being addressed.

Comment: @VaughnCato The *data* is in big endian, and this code reads/writes a big endian format (this is independent of the platform endian). e.g. start by reading into the LSB instead of the MSB of `inbitbuf`, and it would read little endian data.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something like.

```
unsigned char raw[4];
unsigned int val;
if (4 != fread(raw, 1, 4, input)) {
  // error condition, return early or throw or something
}
val = static_cast<unsigned int>(data[3])
    | static_cast<unsigned int>(data[2]) << 8 
    | static_cast<unsigned int>(data[1]) << 16 
    | static_cast<unsigned int>(data[0]) << 24;
```

if you were doing little endian, reverse the indexes and everything stays the same.

A good [rant on endianness](http://commandcenter.blogspot.com/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html) and the code that people seem to write, if you want more.

Comment: Necro post, but I wanted to comment on the Endianness rant - specifically where it DOES matter. If I am using a serial data bus in 32-bit mode, and I have to transmit an address to some external device before I can receive data... if the address is 0x01020304 and I load that into the DATA register for a transfer of a little Endian MCU, guess what actually gets transferred (in MSB first mode)... yep, 0x04030201 <- that's the wrong address. For EEPROM, sometimes an Instruction is sent followed by a 24-bit address. Yeah, sometimes, Endianness absolutely matters.

Answer (score 1):

Its a good idea to mask (perform a bitwise OR against) the bytes one at a time before shifting them . Obviously if you are shifting a 16 bit integer the unmasked bits will just be pushed off either end into oblivion.  But for integers larger that 16 bits (I actually had to use 24 bit integers once) it's best to mask each byte before shifting and recombining (perform a bitwise OR on) them.